# Какие есть библиотеки или методы для постоянного получения снимков экрана?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, поиск-библиотек, скриншоты

Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки или методы для постоянного получения снимков экрана? Максимальная частота снимков - 60/сек, но в случае если на экране ничего не меняется, то достаточно только снимков последовательных изменений. Желательно, чтобы была возможность как снимков отдельных окон, так и всего монитора. Интересуют `linux` и `windows`.

Comment: На Windows есть desktop duplication api, на линукс - по разному.

Comment: Есть готовые программы-шпионы для контроля активности персонала в фирмах. Как называются не скажу, но как-то работал в конторе, в которой такая штука была установлена на всех станциях. И она собирала снимки экрана и передавала на сервер. Вы такую-же пишете?